# Unable to connect SQL Server to an Excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to connect SQL Server to an Excel sheet using get data source. I have two systems: System A has SQL Server installed, and I'm trying to connect to System B using an Excel sheet.

When I provide the details as

```
Server: 10.100.84.224\DOHVP1C00JIRA01 and Database: jiradb1
```

Click on "Ok", I get an error

> Unable to Connect
>   Details: "Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance specified)

I have checked all the connection which are configured and looks fine like port numbers and I followed this link too
[SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754563/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified)

Note: if we want to access System B is VPN secure and we have opened for those too.

Comment: For clarification: I assume you try to connect to an SQL SERVER from Excel, so that you can query the db from excel and display the data in excel as well?

Comment: Exactly, i am looking that

Comment: What is the purpose of the patch behind the servers ip address? The ip should be enough

Comment: My database in "10.100.84.224" server and DB server name is "DOHVP1C00JIRA01". So, in Excel I am trying with these. Let me know if anything wrong in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the TCP/IP is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager for the server end.

Besides, please make sure that the SQL Server is allowed remote connection.

And you use the instance name to connect the server, please ensure that the SQL Server Browser service is started.

By the way, you can ping the IP address to check if the network is we

Comment: TCP/IP as enabled and able to telnet the port. telnet 10.100.84.224 1433. but if you ping the server ip it is showing as timeout. telnet with 8080 and 1433 are working without any issue